# CURL in PHP URL w/ Umlauts

Tags: php, url, curl

Im having a problem with curl: 
I get data from Mysql (City names) with umlauts coded in ascii HEX (e.g. %DF for ß or %DC for ü ).
i convert them with str_replace(); to german Umlauts (ß,ü,ä,ö). 
i get an error when i send the data (the cities) with curl.("fill in the from correct!")

when i send data WITHOUT Umlauts (ä,ö,ü,ß) everything is fine!
Whats wrong with my code or with curl. I also tried it w/ shell - same problem!

```
$this->url = "blah.org/?params=diesdas&city_from=Straßbourg&City_to=München";

$this->ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "cookie");
$this->ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "46.4.248.80");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "3128");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->ckfile);
echo 'getting cookie file...';
$cookie = curl_exec($this->ch);
if($cookie = false){echo 'couldn\'t get cookie!<br> '.curl_error($this->ch);}else{echo 'got cookie! omnomnom!<br>';}

$this->ch = curl_init("blah.com/sendcookietome");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->ckfile);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "46.4.248.80");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "3128");
curl_exec($this->ch);
```

best, meeeeeh!

Comment: They _should_ be urlencoded.... Why do you revert that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work: 
wow.wtf?

this link works for 'ß': 
    blah.org/&from_spar=StraÃŸburg&to_spar=Kiel+Hbf
    blah.org/&from_spar=KÃ¶ln+Hbf&to_spar=Stuttgart+Hbf

Thats how it is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The characters need to be url-encoded if you are using them in GET or POST data. Don't decode them.

Comment: when i lookup "blah.org/?params=diesdas&city_from=Straßbourg&City_to=München" in my browser - everythings fine! when i curl it - i get 'enter form correct'.

Comment: That's because your browser encodes the characters for you, keeping it simple for the user.

Comment: when i let the umlauts urlencoded i cant get the sourcecode from that page.
here the url that fetches the cookie:
http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar=Stra%DFburg&to_spar=Haiger&start_datum=04.07.2012&start_time=06%3A30&end_datum=04.07.2012&end_time=16%3A30&SEA_adults=1&trainclass_spar=2

%DF for ß

and the url that gets the cookie: "http://bahn.ltur.com/details"

Answer (score 0):

Use rawurlencode() for you cities.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Also you misspelled **Straßburg** for there form ....

In your example :

```
$cityname =rawurlencode('Straßburg');

$url ='http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?mnd=de&lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar='.$cityname.'&to_spar=Haiger&start_datum=04.07.2012&start_time=06%3A30&end_datum=06.07.2012&end_time=16%3A42&SEA_adults=1&SEA_kids1=0&SEA_kids2=0&SEA_adult1=&SEA_adult2=&SEA_adult3=&SEA_adult4=&SEA_adult5=&SEA_kid11=&SEA_kid12=&SEA_kid13=&SEA_kid14=&SEA_kid15=&trainclass_spar=2&x=54&y=15
';

//do your curl thing..
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! 
well, the point is, everything is correctly encoded in the DB,  (K%F6ln+Hbf (Köln Hbf), Stra%DFburg (Straßburg), etc.)
When i send the request to fetch the cookie at the above url i get that 'fill in form correctly'.